# Change button text in <owl-date-time> and remove AM/PM from date

Tags: angular, datetimepicker

I am using "https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-pick-datetime" this library for datetime picker. [image] https://stackblitz.com/github/DanielYKPan/owl-examples/tree/date-time-picker. I want to change the button text of **"Set" to "Apply"**.

And after setting the date to input field, there its shows **AM/PM**.I want to remove that.
Can anyone please help me how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs in the Localizing labels and messages section, you can customize these strings through OwlDateTimeIntl - [docs](https://danielykpan.github.io/date-time-picker/):

The various text strings used by the picker are provided through OwlDateTimeIntl.

```
import { OwlDateTimeModule, OwlNativeDateTimeModule, OwlDateTimeIntl} from 'ng-pick- 
datetime';


export class DefaultIntl extends OwlDateTimeIntl = {

/** A label for the cancel button */
cancelBtnLabel= 'Cancel',

/** A label for the set button */
setBtnLabel= 'Set',

/** A label for the hour12 button (AM) */
hour12AMLabel= 'AM',

/** A label for the hour12 button (PM) */
hour12PMLabel= 'PM',
};
```

Comment: I am using the below code to get the picker.
 <input placeholder="Date Time:"
               [(ngModel)]="dateTime"
               [owlDateTimeTrigger]="dt" [owlDateTime]="dt">
        <owl-date-time #dt></owl-date-time>.
In this how can i change the text of "set" to "apply".Can you please tell me.@Capo

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```js
export class DefaultIntl extends OwlDateTimeIntl {
  /** A label for the cancel button */
  cancelBtnLabel= 'Cancelar';

  /** A label for the set button */
  setBtnLabel= 'Aceptar';
};
```

Comment: This is the same answer as my response and adds nothing new.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { OwlDateTimeIntl } from 'ng-pick-datetime';

export class DefaultIntl extends OwlDateTimeIntl {
    cancelBtnLabel = 'Your text'
    setBtnLabel = 'Your text'
};

@NgModule({
        declarations: [],
        imports: [
        ],
        providers: [
            { provide: OwlDateTimeIntl, useClass: DefaultIntl },
        ],
    })
```

Answer (score -1):

The only way to change is go to the root file, that is goto the ng-pick-datetime folder, and go to 'date-time-picker-intl.service.js' file where you can change

```
this.setBtnLabel = 'Set';
```

to

```
 this.setBtnLabel = 'Apply';
```

Answer (score -1):

The format of the class `DefaultDateTimeIntl` should be

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { OwlDateTimeIntl } from '@danielmoncada/angular-datetime-picker';
    
@Injectable()
export class DefaultDateTimeIntl extends OwlDateTimeIntl {
  public cancelBtnLabel = 'Cancel';
  public setBtnLabel = 'Apply Date/Time';
}
```